# Inverting the scrolling of only one mouse

Tags: mouse, xinput, scrolling, libinput, mouse-gestures

Hi I have two mice connected to my machine. One is a standard mouse, the other is a touchpad which, as a device, is split into the touchpad itself and the mouse part.

I would like to set the inverted scrolling in the touchpad but at the same time keeping the natural scrolling in the standard mouse.

I can identify the two devices of interest using `sudo libinput list-devices` :

```
Device:           HP HP Pavilion Gaming Mouse 300
Kernel:           /dev/input/event11
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

and

```
Device:           MSFT0002:00 04F3:31AD Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event22
Group:            12
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

As I told before, I would like to keep the `Nat.scrolling disabled` for the former while `Nat.scrolling enabled` for the latter.

Unfortunately the xinput wayaround is not possible since there is the well known conflict with Xwayland.

Any ideas?